# How to clear input in SlideTextInput (custom TextInput component)?

Tags: react-native

and of course sorry if the question is somewhat dumb.

In the app I'm developing a user should be able to swipe on the TextInput. Since TextInput only listens to taps I used this gist: https://gist.github.com/MikeShi42/87b65984f0a31e38d553cc056fcda017
(BTW @Michael Shi thanks a ton)

However, once I changed TextInput to SlideTextInput the Clear button ceased to work.

```
clearInput() {
    this.setState({text: ''});
}

render() {
    return (
    <Button name='clear' action={this.clearInput} />
    <SlideTextInput 
        style={styles.input} 
        ref='input'
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
        placeholder={this.state.placeholder} 
        value={this.state.text} 
        multiline={true} 
        returnKeyType='done' 
        blurOnSubmit={true} />
    )
}
```

I also tried `this.refs.input.setNativeProps({text: ''});` instead of just passing a new `value` prop (that should be — and was — sufficient for normal TextInput), and calling  `forceUpdate()`, but again to no avail. I don't see much changes in SlideTextInput.js compared to the original TextInput component, but I must be missing something that would explain such bad behaviour?

UPD: the answer was pretty simple in the end. Instead of linking the component to its native counterpart (`ref={this._setNativeRef}`) like original TextInput does, SlideTextInput has it ref'ed to a string (`ref="input"`). I changed it back and voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple in the end. Instead of linking the component to its native counterpart (ref={this._setNativeRef}) like original TextInput does, SlideTextInput has it ref'ed to a string (ref="input") (it's not about props in my code it's about SlideTextInput.js file itself). I changed it back and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it seems that the value props is not being sent to the original TextInput. It is extending the TextInput but it is returning another component without sending the value prop.

Try:

```
this.refs.input.setText('');
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for answering. SlideTextInput actually has a prop `text={this.props.value}` and I just discovered one more thing — Clear button does work if I return to the screen from another one (but it has nothing to do with selectionState of the textinput.

Comment: Is clearInput being actually fired? If you add a log or alert there does it execute every time?

Comment: Oh yes, that was the first thing I checked :) I added `<Text>{this.state.text}</Text>` to the header to see if this.state.text is being successfully cleared upon pressing the button — it is, but the input itself is not. Most amazingly, it actually does clear if your _return_ to this screen, take a look at the [screencast](https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/3G1R3P232R1J473A1D3Q/clear-button-behaviour.mp4)

Comment: That is very weird. Like the state and the input are only synced when you play with it. Have you tried clicking on the input, then clicking on the button? Just to see if that binds the values.

Comment: It actually was doing quite the opposite — since the native/JS link was missing in the SlideTextInput (see my updated post), the values were bound  only after initial mounting (`componentDidMount: function() {this._lastNativeText = this.props.value;}`). This explains why the button worked at first and ceased working after you edited text.